# Applying two filter functions in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to apply two filter functions in Google Spreadsheets:

Column (A) contains new data
Column (B) contains filter data, i.e. cells with text that should not be included in column C
Column (C) is the outcome, i.e. column A minus all the cell data in column B

I use this formula in column C:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(UNIQUE(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0)),A2:A,""))))
```

It works well in the sense that it filters data (in this case e-mail addresses) that should not be included in column C. However, I would also like to be able to filter whole domains, i.e. if the domain example.com is listed in column B then all addresses from column A ending with example.com should be excluded from column C.

See example file I created: **[applying two filters](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqdbkOoUimHcdElJMEpTYllUVDdBWTAybk42VVp3Z1E&authkey=CPGTobIJ&hl=en&authkey=CPGTobIJ#gid=0)**

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have the raw data in a separate sheet or column from the filtered data. Here I'm assuming the raw data is in a sheet named `rawData` column A.

For the filtered dat you can use:

```
=FILTER(rawData!A:A, isError(search("example.com", rawData!A:A)))
```

Put this formula in cell A1 of a new sheet where you want the filtered data.

Comment: You mean like this (www.goo.gl/idyXy)? It's a bit tedious to replace the domain string in the formula on each and every row. Sure there's no easier way of doing this? I had a guy writing a script for me in Excel that I ran every time I needed filtering so I reckon perhaps there's a way of doing something similar in Google Docs.

Comment: Not saying that you should write a script of course, just that there may be a workaround allowing me or whoever reads this to just add data that should be filtered in a column rather than copying/pasting the whole formula into every row. Your help is of course much appreciated, let me know if I can reciprocate somehow.